# Clojure changing binding local's value depending on conditions

Tags: clojure, let

What is the idomatic way to change a local depending on conditions like below? Here I am changing value of x depending on some conditions.

```
(defn person-story
 [person]
  (let [x (str "My name is " (:firstname person) " " (:lastname person) "." )
    x (if (:showaddress person) (str x " I live in " (:address person) ".") x)
    x (if (:showage person) (str x " I am " (:age person) " yrs old. ") x)
    x (if (seq (:hobby person)) (str x " I like " (clojure.string/join ", " (:hobby person)) ".") x)]
x))

(person-story {:firstname "John" :lastname "Doe" :age 45 :showage false :address "67 Circe Ave" :showaddress true :hobby ["movie" "music" "money"]})
```

And that would output:

```
"My name is John Doe. I live in 67 Circe Ave. I like movie, music, money."
```

If I were to do it in java, i would have done something like:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("My name is ");
    sb.append(person.get("firstname")).append(" ");
    sb.append(person.get("lastname")).append(" ");
    if (showaddress) sb.append("I live in ").append(person.get("address")).append(" ");
    if (showage) sb.append("I am ").append(person.get("age")).append(" yrs old. ");
    List<String> hobbies = person.get("hobby");
    if ( hobbies != null && !hobbies.isEmpty()) sb.append("I like "). append(StringUtils.join(hobbies, ", "));
    return sb.toString()
```

What is the best way to achieve the same thing that I am achieving above in clojure? Sorry for the title, I could not come up with a better one.

---

**Solutions**

Thank you xsc and amalloy, both answers were great. I accepted amalloy's answer since it showed a totally new way of solving the problem, but upvoted both.
Here are the snippets for solution in both suggested ways:

amalloy's method:

```
(defn person-story2 [person]
  (let [tests [[:showaddress #(format " I live in %s." (:address %))]
               [:showage #(format " I am %s yrs old." (:age %))]
               [(comp seq :hobbies) #(format " I like %s." (clojure.string/join ", " (:hobbies %)))]]]
    (apply str (format "My name is %s %s." (:firstname person) (:lastname person))
           (for [[test f] tests
                 :when (test person)]
             (f person)))))


(person-story2 {:firstname "John" :lastname "Doe" :showage true :age 50  :showaddress true :address "Universal Studios" :hobbies ["movies" "music" "money"]})
```

output:

```
"My name is John Doe. I live in Universal Studios. I am 50 yrs old. I like movies, music, money."
```

xsc's method:

```
(defn person-story 
  [{:keys [firstname lastname address showaddress age showage hobbies] :as person}]
  (cond-> 
   (str "My name is " firstname " " lastname ". ")
   showaddress (str "I live in " address ". ")
   showage (str "I am " age " yrs old. ")
   (seq hobbies) (str "I like " (clojure.string/join ", " hobbies))))

(person-story {:firstname "John" :lastname "Doe" :showage false :age 50 :address "Universal Studios" :showaddress true :hobbies ["movies" "music" "money"]})
```

output:

```
"My name is John Doe. I live in Universal Studios. I like movies, music, money"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid repeating anything useless (eg, if conditions, or the x you are threading through everything), define a list of the tests you want to run, and the functions to apply if the tests succeed. Then you can just reduce over that list. In the simple case of building a string via repeated calls to str, you can cut out the middleman a bit and just call str yourself, via apply:

```
(defn person-story [person]
  (let [tests [[:showaddress #(format " I live in %s." (:address %))]
               [:showage #(format " I am %s yrs old." (:age %))]
               [(comp seq :hobby) #(format " I like %s." (clojure.string/join ", " (:hobby %)))]]]
    (apply str (format "My name is %s %s." (:firstname person) (:lastname person))
           (for [[test f] tests
                 :when (test person)]
             (f person)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Clojure 1.5 there are `cond->`/`cond->>` that work just like `->`/`->>` with conditionals determining whether a single step is performed:

```
(cond->
  (str "My name is " (:firstname p) " " (:lastname p) ".")
  (:showaddress p) (str "I live in " (:address p) ".")
  (:showage p)     (str "I am " (:age p) " yrs old.")
  ...)
```

This would be the idiomatic solution for conditional string building. Alternatively, you could use something along the lines of:

```
(clojure.string/join
  [(str "My name is " (:firstname p) " " (:lastname p) ".")
   (if (:showaddress p)
     (str "I live in " (:address p) "."))
   ...])
```

This uses the fact that `nil` will be ignored when joining strings.